# Always show Close/Minimize/Maximize buttons (Unity)

Tags: unity, 16.04, window-buttons

There are a few questions about "showing buttons" but these are not what I want. Here's the **System Settings's window buttons** as it has always been.

[image: System Settings window buttons]

And here's what I want in **all** windows. For example, in the System Settings menu, you **can't maximize** the window. But I want the **maximize** button in the window *EVEN if we can't do anything with it*. Likewise when we can **only CLOSE** the window, I want the **maximize** and **minimize** buttons *anyway*. The design of the unclickable buttons is from the one of an inactive window.

Even if it's unclickable I want it in the windows

[image]

Q: So, can we make anything like that by editing some files or **dconf** or something else? Just always show close, minimize, maxmize buttons.

*I am ready to break my Ubuntu, it's just a testing Ubuntu.*

**EDIT: Still don't know how to do, but I found a window that show what I want, in "vanilla" Ubuntu.
So here's the normal window:** [image: Click me]

**And when I maximize the same window I get what I want in the normal window:** [image: Without edit anything]

Q: *So is there a way to get the line(s) of the config file(s) that makes it possible to get this?*

Answer (score 5):

Short answer is no, you can't do this in a trivial manner by just changing settings.

Long answer is that you need to edit the theme to draw the button anyway (probably you want to draw the unfocused version on focused windows), for the specified title bar hints in the theme.

Comment: Yes this is it! But how can i achieve this? Because if we just can't edit files to get what i want, how it will be possible?

Comment: Take the existing theme, copy it to a new theme, and edit to your hearts content. It's not a simple one line fix though. There's plenty of documentation on how to make themes.